# Show Tool Tip View in Android

Tags: android, popup

I want to show a tool tip type popup in android, on a (i) button ( or view ) click, as i have shown in the design.

Is it possible in android, and the i button on which I have to show this tool-tip is already in a popup.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But you'll have to create it yourself. It'll be a custom component. Here's some sample code to achieve this from Android framework engineer Roman Nurik: https://gist.github.com/romannurik/3982005

Answer (score 1):

use [popupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)  to show it
but you need draw your own layout like your sample pic.

```
PopupWindow m_PopUpWindow = new PopupWindow(m_Context);
m_PopUpWindow.setContentView('your layout');
m_PopUpWindow.setHeight('Popup Height');
m_PopUpWindow.setWidth('Popup Width');
m_PopUpWindow.showAsDropDown('where you want to show', 'x pos', 'y pos');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GreenDroid https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid
A collection of Android widgets in that you can use quickactionbar

or 
Go through with this URL http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: This example is good one. Can I show this on A Dialog ? I mean my info button is available on a Dialog

Comment: ya u can do that ...just google this hope u will get that once i have done that but now i don't have the exact code otherwise i posted that one also..if my answer is gud for u accept it